# sharing class instance among processes in CAD application

Tags: python, graphics, multiprocessing

I'm trying to implement multiprocessing feature into my rendering/modeling(CAD) application. I do understand some `threading` but am quite new to `multiprocessing`. So there is a design problem and learning problem at the same time.

I want to address learning problem first and then the real design problem as it could help to understand the real, design, problem.

To generalize my design problem, I've written following example including `Pool` and `Manager`:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import time


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0

    def accum(self):
        self.count += 1

    def get(self):
        return self.count


class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass


MyManager.register('kkk', A)


def count(obj, id):
    print(id, 'start')
    for _ in range(100_000):
        obj.accum()
    return id


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('run single process')
    st = time.time()
    c = 0
    for _ in range(10):
        for __ in range(100_000):
            c += 1
    print(c, f'elapse: {time.time()-st}')
    print()

    print('run multi process')
    st = time.time()
    pool = mp.Pool()
    with MyManager() as manager:
        obj = manager.kkk()
        ps = [pool.apply_async(count, args=(obj, i)) for i in range(10)]
        print('waiting...')
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        print(obj.get(), f'elapse: {time.time()-st}')
```

This is a slightly modified testing code brought from python multiprocessing docs.
Result were as follows:

```py
run single process
1000000 elapse: 0.10909914970397949

run multi process
waiting...
0 start
1 start
4 start
3 start
2 start
5 start
6 start
7 start
8 start
9 start
1000000 elapse: 36.15581750869751
```

So, multiprocessing is very slow here. I've read this and that but can't really build an intuition about multiprocessing. Is this result caused by pickling? Or am I missing something else? I understand this is not a good task to be executed via multiprocessing. But still, is there a way to improve execution time in this type of multiprocessing scenario?

Main concern on this example is to figure out good way to share objects via processes. While main process draws a frame(like in movie file, a sequential images) I thought it would be nice if application could delegate background tasks to another process. Tasks can be such as modifying geometric entities or testing various geometric properties. And obviously these background processes has to have access to preexisting objects such as `model`, `window`, `camera` etc. to do its job. Those objects are big and complicated, hard to degenerate into simple list or another primitives. 
So what approach can I take in this kind of situation? Apologies in advance for quite an ambiguous questioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the slowness is not related to the pickling and unpickling of the arguments to your worker function, `count`, but rather the nature of what the first argument, `obj`, is. I will explain:

You are only invoking your worker function 10 times passing to it `obj` and `i`, which have to be pickled and unpickled 10 times. And what are these arguments? `i` is just an integer but `obj` is a reference to a *proxy* for an instance of class `A`. Again, pickling and unpickling a reference is relatively trivial *compared to invoking 100,000 calls on the proxy for each of the 10 task submissions you are doing*. If the `A` instance were local to each sub-process (of course, if it were you would not be able to share one instance across *all* processes), then each method invocation would not be that expensive. But now you are invoking the method on a proxy that results in the method actually being executed on the instance located in the main process created with the statement `obj = manager.kkk()`. In essence, statement `obj.accum()` in function `count` becomes a remote method invocation. And *that* is what is taking a lot of time.

**Update**

I modified the program to do 4 rather than 10 iterations (I only have 8 cores and life is short) and my timings were:

```
run single process
400000 elapse: 0.0310208797454834

run multi process
waiting...
0 start
1 start
3 start
2 start
400000 elapse: 22.726988077163696
```

Then I modified worker function `count` to ignore the passed `obj` argument and to just increment a local integer variable as follows:

```py
def count(obj, id):
    print(id, 'start')
    c = 0
    for _ in range(100_000):
        c += 1
    return id
```

And these were the new timings:

```
run single process
400000 elapse: 0.03300070762634277

run multi process
waiting...
0 start
2 start
3 start
1 start
0 elapse: 0.19895458221435547
```

So clearly all the time was being taken in executing `obj.accum()`. The multiprocessing version still takes considerably longer due to the time taken just to create the process pool. If you start the clock running after the pool is created and just before the 4 tasks are submitted we get:

```
run single process
400000 elapse: 0.03700995445251465

run multi process
waiting...
0 start
1 start
3 start
2 start
0 elapse: 0.03301692008972168
```

The multiprocessing version now shows a slight improvement. There is still overhead in transferring arguments and results back an forth. We have to make the overhead worthwhile. If we perform 4_000_000 iterations instead of 100_000 iterations, we get:

```
run single process
16000000 elapse: 1.3639805316925049

run multi process
waiting...
0 start
1 start
2 start
3 start
0 elapse: 0.30300235748291016
```

Comment: so telling main process to execute a function, which isn't even blocked, consumes all this time?

Comment: That's what I am saying.